# escaping space from path in powershell when calling msiexec

Tags: powershell

The problem is that there is a space in the path to the uninstall file that is stored in variable     `$uninstall32`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\uninstall.exe
```

How can I escape the space and execute the uninstall file using msiexec?

```
$softwaretoRemove = "Notepad\+\+"
$uninstall32 = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match $softwaretoRemove } | select UninstallString

$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.UninstallString -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
$uninstall32 = $uninstall32.Trim()
Write $uninstall32
start-process "msiexec.exe"  -ArgumentList "$uninstall32 /uninstall /quiet"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround the path with quotes:

```
start-process "msiexec.exe"  -ArgumentList """$uninstall32"" /uninstall /quiet"
```